Google pay button doesn't display in test mode with stripe react native
The Google Pay button doesn't display when the app is in test mode. However, in live mode, the Google Pay option displays, but I can't complete the payment because I need to get approval first. To get approval, I need to run it in test mode, take screenshots, and submit them for the review process. In that case, I'm stuck.
I have already checked with a real device (which has the Google Pay Wallet) and joined the test card suite at https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite.
In test mode, it displays the 'Link' payment method.
Any ideas?

As a first step, did you enable Google Pay in testmode in your payment method settings : https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/payment_methods? If it's already turned on, I suggest you write in to Stripe Support who can probably look further into the issue
